# Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' Task failed with an exception. - What went wrong: java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: javascript, react-native

moeen@moeen-HP-ProBook-640-G4:~/Downloads/TS-app-routes_issue$ npx react-native run-android
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
35 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 34 up-to-date
/home/moeen/Downloads/TS-app-routes_issue/android/app/src/main/java/com/techstuffapp/MainApplication.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
^
symbol:   class PackageList
location: package com.facebook.react
/home/moeen/Downloads/TS-app-routes_issue/android/app/src/main/java/com/techstuffapp/newarchitecture/MainApplicationReactNativeHost.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
^
symbol:   class PackageList
location: package com.facebook.react
/home/moeen/Downloads/TS-app-routes_issue/android/app/src/main/java/com/techstuffapp/MainApplication.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
List packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
^
symbol: class PackageList
/home/moeen/Downloads/TS-app-routes_issue/android/app/src/main/java/com/techstuffapp/newarchitecture/MainApplicationReactNativeHost.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
List packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
^
symbol:   class PackageList
location: class MainApplicationReactNativeHost
Note: /home/moeen/Downloads/TS-app-routes_issue/android/app/src/debug/java/com/techstuffapp/ReactNativeFlipper.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
4 errors

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
/home/moeen/Downloads/TS-app-routes_issue/android/app/src/main/java/com/techstuffapp/MainApplication.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
^
symbol:   class PackageList
location: package com.facebook.react
/home/moeen/Downloads/TS-app-routes_issue/android/app/src/main/java/com/techstuffapp/newarchitecture/MainApplicationReactNativeHost.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
^
symbol:   class PackageList
location: package com.facebook.react
/home/moeen/Downloads/TS-app-routes_issue/android/app/src/main/java/com/techstuffapp/MainApplication.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
List packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
^
symbol: class PackageList
/home/moeen/Downloads/TS-app-routes_issue/android/app/src/main/java/com/techstuffapp/newarchitecture/MainApplicationReactNativeHost.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
List packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
^
symbol:   class PackageList
location: class MainApplicationReactNativeHost
Note: /home/moeen/Downloads/TS-app-routes_issue/android/app/src/debug/java/com/techstuffapp/ReactNativeFlipper.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
4 errors

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

```
at makeError (/home/moeen/Downloads/TS-app-routes_issue/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
at /home/moeen/Downloads/TS-app-routes_issue/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (/home/moeen/Downloads/TS-app-routes_issue/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
at async Command.handleAction (/home/moeen/Downloads/TS-app-routes_issue/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:142:9)
```

react native build failed

Comment: sure, lots of errors ... I mean there are a LOT there ... but no question